# How to apply single date filter to power bi report using Angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, powerbi-embedded

Using advanced filter we can apply date range filter to a power bi report but how to apply a single date filter, Please help, I struggled a lot.

getting below error
Undefined property is invalid

```
const filter: IBasicFilter = {
      $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic", filterType: FilterType.Basic,
      values: "2023-04-17 00:00:00",
      operator: 'Equal',
      target: {
        column: 'State',
        table: 'creationDate',
      }
    };

 try {
        await report.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add, [filter]);
        console.log("Report filter was added.");
        }
        catch (errors) {
        console.log(errors);
        }
```

Above filter is not working, Please help..

Comment: Are you able to apply the date filter?

Answer (score 0):

The IBasicFilter interface is expecting the values property to an array:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-models/ibasicfilter#powerbi-models-ibasicfilter-values

Try it like this:

```js
const filter: IBasicFilter = {
  $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
  filterType: FilterType.Basic,
  values: ["2023-04-17 00:00:00"],
  operator: 'Equal',
  target: {
    table: 'creationDate',
    column: 'State'
  }
};
```

Comment: type '"Equal"' is not assignable to type 'BasicFilterOperators', the expected type comes from property operator which is declared here on type IBasicFilter (In, Not In , All)  -- getting this error after using your code.

Comment: Ok! try to define table before defining column